# Temperature monitoring failure

Tags: system, temperature

I have been building a program that records the CPU temperature. I have used the command 'cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp' to check the temperatures and initially it worked fine. Suddenly I noticed that the command does not work anymore and realized that /sys/class/thermal/ does NOT contain any 'thermal_zone' folders anymore. Only cooling_device* folders are present.

Can anybody tell me what has happened to the folders and how to restore them? Should I be worried about me CPU cooling now?

Comment: I can't answer specifically, only to say I have noticed these sys folders can sometimes change even between boots so I don't think you can assume they will stay the same. For example I used to use Conky to monitor `/sys/class/hwmon` which for me contain folders `hwmon0` to `hwmon3` some boots `hwmon3` would contain CPU core temps but on another boot a different day `hwmon3` would contain some other temperature sensor. The only way to be sure was to look at the `name` file within each folder. Now with Conky you can reference temp sensors by name so it's not a problem.

Comment: What is your processor make and model? Did you your kernel version change? If you boot the old kernel does it work?